# Delete all music from iPhone

Tags: ios, music, storage, macos

How do I delete all music from an iPhone 5?
It got loaded from my computer without me checking the box.
I tried to follow the directions from one search result with no success.

Comment: I'm going to put this on hold. If you can link to the specific search results and explain why they don't help you we might be able to open this up for additional answers.

Comment: followed the steps but after (manage Storage) there is no Music to slide .

Answer (score 1):

If you are on iOS 8, you can go to Settings > General > Usage > Storage > Manage Storage > Music, slide the first item "All Songs" to the left and press "Delete".

[image: Manage storage: Music iOS]
[image: Manage storage, delete Music iOS 8]

Warning: there is no confirmation dialog, as I've just found out :|

Answer (score 0):

If the music is purchased from iTunes Store: You can either swipe right and click delete and/or go to Settings>Music> Turn off Show All Music. It could be showing you music purchased called iTunes in the Cloud.

If the music is from the computer: 
You can connect the device to the computer and click on the device in iTunes when it appears. Upon choosing the device, there is a settings list off to the left. Select music and uncheck Sync Music. Then, click apply in the lower right corner.